# Get Update Count in Flow

Tags: dml, screen-flow

I am using the `Update Record` element in a screen flow on the *Specify conditions to identify records, and set fields individually* setting. Is there a way to get a count of how many fields have been updated by the element?

Comment: This would require introspection of that Flow element using the metadata api. Why is this important?

Comment: Since the update is conditional and not all the user input might pass the condition I was thinking of showing the user "updated X out of Y objects" without doing an extra GET before. I was hoping the UPDATE element returned it OOTB.